# Can 'nowhere' be used as a subject?

Tags: subjects, subject-verb-inversion

I am utterly confused... The thing is I was helping a friend do an exercise in which she needed to put some words in the correct order to form a grammatical English sentence. The words in question were:

in / my / Nowhere / shop / than / ice cream / town / sells / else / our / uncle's / better

I was at a loss because I could not find a way to make a proper sentence using those words. My proposal was *Nowhere else in town does ice cream sell better than in my uncle's shop*, but in that case I would need an extra preposition and an auxiliary for inversion.

The plot thickens. When my friend asked her professor, he said that the correct answer should be *Nowhere else in our town sells better ice cream than my uncle's shop*. This sounds completely wrong to me. Am I losing my mind?

Comment: There’s no *better* in that list of words

Comment: << Nowhere sells better ice cream than my uncle's shop. >> uses _nowhere_ metonymically (_people_ sell things but we often draft in establishments as substitutes, notionally here ('no other establishment'). _Somewhere_ and _nowhere_ may be post-modified by else, and _nowhere else_ by a prepositional phrase etc ('Nowhere else on Earth / east of the Mississippi / ...' ).

Comment: Your sentence uses "sell". The list of words has "sells".

Comment: It is just a puzzle question.  **Nowhere else in our town sells better ice cream than my uncle's shop**

Answer (score 1):

"nowhere" can be a pronoun, meaning "no place" and it goes without saying that it may serve as a subject. https://www.lexico.com/definition/nowhere

Comment: It doesn't follow that just because something is a pronoun that it can be the subject of a finite clause. You can’t do so using the pronoun *him* as the subject, and you’ll likely be hard pressed to do so using the pronoun *whose* as the subject, too. Just remember this: nowhere isn’t somewhere you can go. In fact, nowhere isn’t anywhere at all.

Comment: @tchrist Yet "nowhere" is the subject of your last sentence.

Comment: The OED  has an example from DH Lawrence: "Nowhere is far off, in these small wall-girdled cities."